# Extract values from defaultdict if there are more than one

Tags: python

I got the defaultdict called 'anagrams', that looks like this:

```
defaultdict(set,
            {'a': {'a'},
             'act': {'act', 'cat', 'tac'},
             'hitw': {'with'},
             'acn': {'can'},
             'eikl': {'like'},
             'ehty': {'they'},
             'eilnst': {'listen', 'silent'},
             'or': {'or'},
             'be': {'be'}})
```

Now, I would like to list only the values if there is more than one of them assigned to a single key. I've been searching the web forever for a (list) comprehension that could do the trick, but  I'm out of luck.

The result should be like:

```
[{'act', 'cat', 'tac'}, {'listen', 'silent'}]
```

Could someone give a hint?

Comment: It's regular list comprehension over values in the dict `dict.values()` with condition that check that number of items in a value (which is a set) is greater than 1

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> d = {'a': {'a'},
...              'act': {'act', 'cat', 'tac'},
...              'hitw': {'with'},
...              'acn': {'can'},
...              'eikl': {'like'},
...              'ehty': {'they'},
...              'eilnst': {'listen', 'silent'},
...              'or': {'or'},
...              'be': {'be'}}
>>>
>>> [v for v in d.values() if len(v) > 1]
[{'act', 'cat', 'tac'}, {'listen', 'silent'}]
```